# How to auto select in dropdown asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

Have a web page that will enroll students, they have to fill their personal information and then it is saved, but when they have to modify it for some reason I set two dropdowns which load all the states and their counties, but the issue is that I dont know how to auto select the same state than the one which is saved in database for each student, Could somebody help me to do that? below is the code I'm working on :

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 DDOWNState.DataTextField = dr["State"].ToString();
 DDOWNCounty.DataTextField = dr["County"].ToString();
```

Comment: have you use Item.Selected=true;?
If not than
i am writing a solution which will work Inshallah

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
DDOWNState.DataTextField = dr["State"].ToString();
DDOWNState.DataBind();

DDOWNCounty.DataTextField = dr["County"].ToString();
DDOWNCounty.DataBind();
```

Comment: it didn't work, I think so that there is a way by setting an id for each state but I don't know how to do that. I have a stored procedure which returns the state and the id_state but don't know how to relate them to the dropdown when the information for each student is loaded.

Comment: You can use DDOWNState.DataValueField = "Id";

Comment: @ACastle DDOWNState.DataValueField = "Id";  and DDOWNCounty.DataValueField = "id" here id is what you have assigned already to those dropdowns

Comment: Thank you everybody, this post was helpful I have already resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following code. It will help you.
Whenever you used to bind dataSources(DataTable,DataSet,etc...) into Dropdown or any other server controls you should use the Datasource and  Databind property as below.

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DDOWNState.DataSource=dr;
DDOWNState.DataTextField = dr["State"].ToString();
DDOWNState.DataBind();

DDOWNCounty.DataSource=dr;
DDOWNCounty.DataTextField = dr["County"].ToString();
DDOWNCounty.DataSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have binded the `DropDownList` with it's items. Now, you need to do something like this after binding code.

```
DDOWNState.ClearSelection(); //You need to clear first.
DDOWNState.Items.FindByText(dr["State"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

`ClearSelection()` function needs to be run before selecting any other item in `dropdownlist` because the `dropdownlist` allows only one item to be selected at a time. Note that **it does not remove items** from the `dropdownlist`, but only clears the selection so that you can select any other `ListItem`.

You can do the same, if you saved value in database by using `FindByValue()` function as the same way. This will certainly help you.

Comment: This way worked, but then when I chagedthe state I get an error that says :Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Comment: Second line will help you. You need to clear the selection first.

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to check ether the Student's State is match with your database's State as Shown in code

```
// Let Say We have Student's Current state is USA
string curruntState = "USA";

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (curruntState.ToUpper() == reader["State"].ToString().ToUpper())
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(reader["State"].ToString(), reader["StateID"].ToString());
        item.Selected = true;
        ddStates.Items.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {

        ListItem item = new ListItem(reader["State"].ToString(), reader["StateID"].ToString());
        item.Selected = false;
        ddStates.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
ddStates.DataBind();
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For auto select drop-down list which is dependent on other you just need to add

```
<asp:DropDownList ID-"DropDownList1" runat="server" onSelectedIndexChanged-"DropDownList1 SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

Set autopostback property="true"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

if (DropDownListi.selectedvalue=="1")

{

DropDownList2.selectedValue = "1";

}
```